# Snackbar no suitable parent found from the given view

Tags: android

I am running the project where i got the error that no suitable parent found from the given view.
Logcat error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:158)
at com.example.uberclone.ui.home.HomeFragment.init(HomeFragment.java:133)
at com.example.uberclone.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:119)

this is my code

```
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    init();

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return root;
}

private void init() {

    onlineRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(".info/connected");

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), getString(R.string.permission_require), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), getString(R.string.permission_require), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

you are not providing parent view to the snackbar try using this code.